# Formatear salida Json con jq

Tags: json

Necesitaria formatear con JQ el siguiente json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "IP": "192.168.1.1",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site1"
      ],
      "use": false
    },
    {
     "ID": 2,
      "IP": "192.168.1.2",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site2"
      ],
      "use": false
    },
    ...
```

El formato esperado deberia de ser con la salida "ID, IP, locations":

```
1, 192.168.1.1, UK,site1
2, 192.168.1.2, UK,site2
3, 192.168.1.3, LO,site3
```

Como lo puedo adaptar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

[Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
 json = {
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "IP": "192.168.1.1",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site1"
      ],
      "use": false
    },
    {
     "ID": 2,
      "IP": "192.168.1.2",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site2"
      ],
      "use": false
    }]};

// recorremos el json utilizando destructuring 
    for (let { ID : id, IP:ip , locations: [c,s]  } of json.data) {
            console.log(`id es ${id}, ip es ${ip} locations es ${c} , ${s}`)
    }
```

o puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    json = {
  "data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "IP": "192.168.1.1",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site1"
      ],
      "use": false
    },
    {
     "ID": 2,
      "IP": "192.168.1.2",
      "locations": [
        "UK",
        "Site2"
      ],
      "use": false
    }]};
    
 for (x of json.data) {
        console.log(`id es ${x.ID}, ip es ${x.IP} locations es ${x.locations[0]} , ${x.locations[1]}`)
    }
```